# Training from a dataset with hidden positives

Tags: regression, missing-data

I am trying to predict a certain binary variable $Y\in\{0;1\}$ given a feature vector $X$. I want to train a predictor for $Y$ or $P(Y=1|X)$.

Assume for simplicity that I would naturally use logistic regression (I will appreciate an answer with actually any model/method you like). I expect that $Y$ depends a lot on $X$ and that the predictive power will be very strong. If some pairs $(x,y)$ were known as a training set, this would be a classical case of supervised learning.

But I only have a dataset consisting of two parts $A$ and $B$ such as:

- For all lines $(x,y)$ in $A$, $y=0$    ($A$ contains only negatives)
- For all lines $(x,y)$ in $B$, $y$ is unknown, we only know $x$ ($B$ contains both negatives and positives but we don't know who is who)

How would you do to train a predictor for $Y$ with this kind of dataset?

You can assume that the datasets were not artificially split: they originate from the same dataset where every positive line was put in $B$, every negative line was put in $A$ or in $B$ randomly (independently of $X$) with a certain probability.

Answer (score 0):

The training data is consistent with the model 

    `y = 0`

It doesn't sound like that is the model you want. So you know something about the problem other than the training data. 
I suggest that whatever that other knowledge is, express it as a Bayesian prior. Then use a Bayesian model.

Example: you are playing a game where a coin is tossed repeatedly. It is biased, and you want to estimate the probability of heads. The rule of the game is that if it shows heads, your opponent must say "heads", and if it shows tails, your opponent can choose whether to say "heads" or "tails".

How can you estimate the probability of the coin showing heads? Clearly you can make an upper bound - every time your opponent says tails it is true. To get any better than this, you must make some assumptions about the prior distribution of the bias and of your opponent's strategy.

Comment: I like your rephrasing as a game. Call $p$ the true probability of tails, $q$ the probability that your opponent says the truth when tails. The probability of "he says tails" is $pq$. Any pair $(p,q)$ with same product is equally likely (same outcome). But when there is a $x$, I think this is different as long as $q$ does not depend on $x$. I've added an additional hypothesis to the question.

Comment: I suggest training a classifier for sets A and B - because I don't really see what else you can do.

Comment: I suggest training a classifier for sets A and B - because I don't really see what else you can do. Use a higher weight for A, since every point in A is known to be negative. Then predict negative for x values that are predicted to be in A, and positive for X values predicted to be in B. I'm assuming here that P(A|negative) is independent of x.